# Bottom right border on ion-item

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a ion-item described as:

```
  <ion-row>
  <ion-item class = "Checkbox">
<ion-label>Remember my choice</ion-label>
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="remember"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
```

where the Checkbox class is described as:

```
.Checkbox {
   color: white;
   background:#c34545;
}
```

The problem is that this gives my ion-item a weird bottom right border which you can check out:

[image: Half border]

I found the border property on the button class as:

```
button {
border: 0;
border-top-color: initial;
border-top-style: initial;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-color: initial;
border-right-style: initial;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-color: initial;
border-bottom-style: initial;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: initial;
border-left-style: initial;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
```

But disabling it gives me this:

[image: Full border]

This is really making me pull my hair out. The only other possible conflict in the scss file is the ion-row that I have defined:

```
ion-row {
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: please clarify how exactly u want?

Comment: Seems like the `ion-label` has a border bottom attribute.

Comment: @Santhoshkumar To remove the bottom border in the first picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, thanks to Mr.Bellians' comment. I went and took another look.

```
.item-md.item-block .item-inner {
padding-right: 8px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  }
```

As you can see it has a border-bottom. I overrided it in my scss file and it looks fine now.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to remove the bottom line is to add `no-lines` property to `ion-item`. No need to add any `css` styles.

Comment: In ionic 4 use lines="none"

Comment: For ionic5 `lines="none"` was not enough ... had to add css override:
`on-item:last-child {--inner-border-width: 0; }`
[see here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v4-how-to-remove-last-child-bottom-border-of-ion-item-in-ionic4/157361/5?u=theunsa)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the ion-item tag an argument named lines with the value of none.

```
<ion-item lines="none">
```

Comment: Works for Ionic 5